# APEX REST Service permission in profiles and Permission Sets

Tags: rest-api, profile, apexrest, permission-sets

I have code which makes Rest callouts to an external system for authorization and rest of the working. 
As per our design team APEX REST Service permission should be disabled.

I tested out this is not needed to make the callout, only API Enabled permission in the permission set is required.

However, I need to provide reasons and difference between these two permisssion and the specific purpose.

Note: I googled this out, and as per W-18 release notes, they Say APEX Rest service when only resat callouts are made, and API Enabled needed when Rest, SOAP callouts are made, however when I disabled API Enabled and just kept APEX Rest services, the callouts diddn't work.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what those permissions do. Apex REST means that users can call Apex classes, while API enabled means users can use the API. These are *inbound* calls to Salesforce, not outbound. You may be asking the wrong questions.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, this clears the confusion. Wondering if there is any permission for just allowing the SOAP inbound access specifically.